# How to find a character index in input text?

Tags: javascript, html

I created 2 input text field in html.The first input text gonna contain a long random text,the second input text gonna contain a character.If you click the button,you need to get the index of this character in the long random text.I try to solve it,but this is a little bit hard for me.I think i have to use the "indexof" in js but i dont know how.Maybe.I think i have to create 2 string,which contain the long random text,and the character as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply would do `str.indexOf(value)`. Here's an interactive example:

```js
var str = document.getElementById("string").innerHTML;
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var button = document.getElementById("search");
var output = document.getElementById("output");
function searchForString() {
  output.textContent = "Index of string \"" + input.value + "\": " + str.indexOf(input.value);
}
```

```html
String: <span id="string">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</span><br />
<label for="input">Find this character: </label><input id="input" type="text"><br />
<button id="search" onclick="searchForString()">Search</button><br />
<div id="output"></div>
```